# Use JS variable for fancybox data-src value

Tags: javascript, html, variables, iframe, fancybox-3

I have an expandable search bar that collects search input from the user and then redirects them to a search-focused php page with the search for their input already displayed. Works great.

I'm trying to open a fancybox iframe for the search.php page. I have one issue that feels like it should be so simple but haven't been able to overcome – I can't figure out how to update the data-src value that fancybox uses to a URL that includes the search input. I have the fully parsed URL that I need in a js variable but I can't figure out how to get 'data-src' to use it.  If I hard code the URL in quotes, it works the way I want it to, so I just need help figuring out how to use my JS string variable instead of a hard-coded URL.

Here is my search input html:

```
<div class="infobarsearch-container">
   <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
      <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="">

          <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="search" value="" name="q" id="search">

          <input id="searchbtn" name="searchbtn" class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" onclick="searchstuff()" value="" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="THIS NEEDS TO BE THE VALUE OF SEARCHINPUT FROM SEARCHSTUFF()" data-caption="My Caption">

          <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the onclick function where I build the parsed url that includes the search input.  The JS variable with the complete url that I need to use is 'searchinput':

```
function searchstuff()
   {
      var searchinp = document.getElementById('search');
      searchinput = "inputs/search.php?search=" + searchinp.value;
      alert("searchinput: " + searchinput);
   }
```

And here is the fancybox initialization for this use on the page:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
   toolbar  : false,
   smallBtn : true,
   afterClose: function () {
      parent.location.reload(true);
   }

$(".searchbtn").fancybox({
   toolbar  : false,
   smallBtn : true,
});
```

I hope you can help.  I need to get the url string value stored in the 'searchinput' variable in searchstuff() to be used by 'data-src' in the searchbtn input element.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a setAttribute to your click event handler like:

```
document.querySelector('#searchbtn').setAttribute('data-src',searchinput);


function searchstuff()
   {
      var searchinp = document.getElementById('search');
      var searchBtn = document.querySelector('#searchbtn');
      var searchinput = "inputs/search.php?search=" + searchinp.value;
      searchBtn.setAttribute('data-src',searchinput);
      alert("searchinput: " + searchinput);
   }
```

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks so much for taking the time.